# web api Route attribute not found

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2013, asp.net-web-api

I need to implement a Method in my web service, which is available by a defined route.
So I used the `Route` attribute like this:

```
    [Route("api/New")]
    public void CreateNew(int id)
    {
        //Do stuff
    }
```

But VS2013 says that the namespace "Route" can't be found.

I guess this can be solved by installing a nuget package.

Can anybody help?

Comment: That's not even valid C#, it's `[Route("api/Patient")]`

Comment: sure...but problem stays

Comment: Have you got a reference to System.Web.Http in your application?

Comment: yes. there is the reference

Comment: Which version of webapi ?

Comment: "Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi" version="4.0.30506.0"

Comment: Maybe take a look at [attribute routing](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2) documentation for web api.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Attribute Routing is native in ASP.NET MVC 5, or later, and ASP.NET Web API 2.
check your MVC version it should be above the 4.

Comment: remove that reference and add again that reference.

Comment: reinstalled "Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.WebHost"

Answer (score 2):

1. Install-Package AttributeRouting (for MVC)
2. Install-Package AttributeRouting.WebApi (for Web API)
3. Install-Package AttributeRouting.WebApi.Hosted (for self-hosted Web API)