# adding Route Attribute to ApiController

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm developing an ASP.NET Web Api app with .NET Framework 4.0 and C#.

I have this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Http;
using System.Web.Http;

namespace MyProject.Web.Api.Controllers
{
    public class UserADController : ApiController
    {
        [HttpGet]
        [Route("api/UserAD/GetAllUsers")]
        public HttpResponseMessage GetAllUsers()
        {
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;


            return response;
        }

    }
}
```

But there isn't a RouteAttribute on System.Web.Http.dll (this is in `\packages\Microsoft.AspNet.WebApi.Core.4.0.30506.0\lib\net40\System.Web.Http.dll`).

Attribute Routing is native in ASP.NET MVC 5, or later, and ASP.NET Web API 2.

What is the equivalent for this Route attribute in this ASP.NET version?

Comment: what you mean by "there isn't a RouteAttribute on System.Web.Http.dll" ? EDIT: maybe duplicated with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29841993/web-api-route-attribute-not-found

Comment: and be sure you got the proper routing configuration enabled this way: http://goo.gl/D4mTpz [asp.net link]

Comment: You really want to move to Web API 2.3.3 if you can.

Comment: @YishaiGalatzer Yes, I know and I want to move to it but in my company they don't want :(.

Comment: Let them know that WebAPI 2.3.3 is compatible with WebAPI 1.0 and has numerous bug fixes performance improvements and other enhancements over the new features. Notice that all bug fixes (other than security fixes) are only applied to the latest version, so you have round about 8 RTM releases between 1.0.0 to 2.3.3 with tons of bug fixes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want Attribute Based routing in **ASP.Net WebAPI 1**, then install this nuget -

```
Install-Package AttributeRouting.WebApi
```

Then decorate your controller action -

```
[GET("api/value")]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{
    return new string[] { "value1", "value2" };
}
```

Then run the solution -

[image]